# DB2: Retrieve related tablename for a column

Tags: db2

I want to check column values of a specific table, but forgot the tablename. I only have the column names. What can I do?

I remember that I can get the tablenames from the DB2 catalog with:

```
select tabname from syscat.tables
```

What is the query to retrieve the tables related to a particular column in DB2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do:

```
select tabschema, tabname
from syscat.columns
where colname='myColumnOfInterest'
```

The column metadata is stored in [SYSCAT.COLUMNS](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS6NHC/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0001038.html).

Comment: Thank you..It helps

Answer (score 0):

In DB2 for i

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, SYSTEM_TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, SYSTEM_COLUMN_NAME
FROM QSYS2/SYSCOLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'YOUCOLUMNAME' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'YOURLIB'
```